# Assignment in Haskell within for block

Tags: function, for-loop, haskell

I'm trying to make a function that calculates the factorial of a number. It is marking an error in the assignment and I don't know how to correct it.

```
for list action = mapM_ action list

main :: IO Int
main = do
    x <- getLine
    for [1..read x] (\ i -> do        
        let tmp = 0                    
        tmp <- tmp*i                   
                                       
        )
    return (tmp)
```

Comment: I would suggest avoiding IO and `for` for now, just write a pure factorial function using recursion. Then you can plug that into main like this: `main = do x <- getLine; print (factorial (read x))`.

Comment: Please *don't* use `for`, and the `tmp` will not work either, since variables are immutable: once assigned a value, you can't assign a different one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, a note on loops. I'll assume [`for_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:for_). Haskell doesn't have any loop keywords, but its monad-paradigm is sufficiently flexible so they can just be implemented as library functions.

However, Haskell does not have mutable variables. So something like `tmp <- tmp*i` can never make sense.

(N.B., you *can* actually write `let tmp = tmp*i`, but don't do it. It accomplishes nothing useful; instead of updating the variable it *defines* a variable, but with a nonsensical circular definition referring to its own result, i.e. this is just a non-terminating computation.)

Ok, that about not having mutable variables is not quite true. These *are* also available from the standard library, they're called [`IORef`s](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-IORef.html). They can't be updated with `<-` or `=` syntax though, but with the `IO` actions defined in the `Data.IORef` module. The following does work:

```
import Data.Foldable (for_)
import Data.IORef

main :: IO ()
main = do
    x <- getLine
    tmp <- newIORef 1
    for_ [1 .. read x] (\ i -> do        
        modifyIORef tmp (*i)
        )
    readIORef tmp
```

Note that there is no `return`. In Haskell, [`return`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:return) is not a keyword (*notice a theme?*) but simply a function injecting a pure value (in this case an `Int`) into a monadic action (in this case `IO Int`). But reading the `IORef` is itself already an impure action, thus you should simply use it as the last line.

Returning a value from `main` is not what you probably want though (the return value is ignored); I reckon you meant to print it instead:

```
import Data.Foldable (for_)
import Data.IORef

main :: IO ()
main = do
    x <- getLine
    tmp <- newIORef 1
    for_ [1 .. read x] (\ i -> do        
        modifyIORef tmp (*i)
        )
    result <- readIORef tmp
    print result
```

Alright, so that's the literal fix to you problem.

**However**, it is strongly recommended *not* to use `IORef` for something like this. Generally the whole philosophy of Haskell is to avoid side effects like mutation. Instead, you should define you function by recursion, and only use `IO` at the very end to print the full result. There are a myriad examples of this, a humorous one is [The Evolution of a Haskell Programmer](https://willamette.edu/%7Efruehr/haskell/evolution.html).

Comment: @chi yeah, fair enough.

Comment: @AlejandroCaro well, I had originally included [`Control.Monad.forM_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:forM_) but the chi pointed out that [`Data.Foldable.for_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:for_) is nowadays preferred. Of course the import needs to be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Making a few small modifications the code worked. I already posted those modifications in your answer

Comment: It's not unreasonable to have such definitions, but in case of `for_` (or the older `forM_`) there's really no point since the standard version is completely established and costs nothing but one character.

Comment: On the other hand, this one is working (https://onecompiler.com/haskell/3zm9ktbwv)

Comment: Oh yeah, it's `Data.Foldable` not `Control.Foldable`.

Answer (score 4):

Haskell is a functional language. One if the aspects of such languages is that variables are *immutable*: once assigned a value, you can never alter that value.

As a result, Haskell has no builtin `for` loops, etc. Its "workhorse" is *recursion*: we recurse until a certain value is determined. For the factorial case, this will look like:

```
factorial :: Int -> Int
factorial 0 = 1
factorial n = …
```

and then the main can look like:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    n <- readLn
    print (factorial n)
```

or shorter:

```
main :: IO ()
main = readLn >>= print . factorial
```